# labelling variables pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In df, there are a lot of variables , included of `vaccine_preg`, `only_breastf` and so on .

As data dictionary ,

```
vaccine={'1':'Anti Tetanus Toxoid Injection', '2':'Polio Vaccine', '3':'BCG vaccine'}
yndk={'1':'yes','0':'no','-88':'Prefer not to answer', '-99':"Don't know"}

df=df.vaccine_preg.map(vaccine)
df=df.only_breastf.map(yndk)
```

I want to do label all variables in data set of this dataframe.
But , after label to `vaccine_preg` variable, Could not continue to label next variable : `only_breast`.

Error is like ;

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'only_breastf'

Help me with this , how to label variables with respective dictionary.

Comment: since map() returns a series..thats why u r getting that error..also can u psot ur df

Comment: These are in panda df ,

agree={'1':'agree','0':"don't agree"} 
list_agg=["anc_ir_fo_daily","anc_att_vac_neg", 
          "anc_iodine", "anc_danger_neg",
          "bf_firsthour", "bf_sixmonths_neg", 
          "bf_prev_dehy_neg", "gen_ors_zinc" ] 

 I want to label list_agg with agree dictionary in looping
 My code : 
     
 for x in list_agg:
     df.x=df.x.map(agree)
     
when I run this code ,
     Error like
     AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'x'
     
Please help also !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do:

```
df.vaccine_preg=df.vaccine_preg.map(vaccine)
df.only_breastf=df.only_breastf.map(yndk)
```

If not your first line is overwriting your dataframe with the series returned from

```
df.vaccine_preg.map(vaccine)
```